# Rotating logo back and forward

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need logo to rotate in 400degree and then rotate back on 360 degree on mouseOver,
then on mouseOut it should roate -400 and then back for 40 degree.
Here is what i accomplished.

```
$("#logo").rotate({ 
bind:
 { 
    mouseover : function() { 
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:400})
    },

    mouseout : function() { 
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:-40})
    }
 } 

});
```

Comment: use css better and simple than javascript

Comment: can you edit your question and just write a "event" : "result", like "mouse in" : "rotate 40deg"

Comment: Usually a question means the use of "`?`". What's your issue? Also what should `.rotate()` be?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i dont know how to rotate back on mouseOver for 40 degree xD
http://jsfiddle.net/qhd83jqn/45/

Comment: dont you mean "mouseOut" maybe?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it should be like this http://www.keecker.com/

Comment: got it to work like in that keeper website, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add 2 extra arguments for the rotate function:

- callback: this is a function that runs when the rotate is done, here you pull it back the -40deg.
- duration: this is the duration of the rotate in ms.

your code would look like that:

```js
$("#logo").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 400,
                callback: function () {
                    $(this).rotate({
                        animateTo: 360
                    });
                },
                duration: 400
            });

        },

        mouseout: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: -40,
                callback: function () {
                    $(this).rotate({
                        animateTo: 0
                    });
                },
                duration: 400
            });
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<img id="logo" src="http://www.keecker.com/img/logo_circle.png">
```

**UPDATE:**

for future reference, people who prefer to achieve the same with pure css, here is a possible solution:

```css
#logo {
    -webkit-animation: rotate_backwards 1s forwards;
    animation: rotate_backwards 1s;
}
#logo:hover {
    -webkit-animation: rotate_forward 1s forwards;
    animation: rotate_forward 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate_forward {

    60% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(400deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate_backwards {

    60% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-400deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate_forward {

    60% {
        transform:rotate(400deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate_backwards {

    60% {
        transform:rotate(-400deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://www.keecker.com/img/logo_circle.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
#logo      {margin:30px; transition:1s;}
#logo:hover{transform:rotate(-400deg);}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="//placehold.it/100x100/f0f&text=LOGO">
```

Comment: Roko :) Happy new year :)

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need action only on hover ..simple to use css :hover instead of javascript

```
#logo{
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#logo:hover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6mfwnyr/3/)